# Connected metric space of first category

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness, baire-category

Question:

> Does there exist a connected metric space of first category (i.e. it can be written as a countable union of nowhere dense subsets)?

No such example is given in the book Counterexamples in Topology. Thus, it seems no easy task. I came across [this paper](https://staff.fnwi.uva.nl/j.vanmill/papers/preprints/connected-final.pdf) today, which proves the existence of a countable dense homogeneous (CDH) metric space which is connected and meager-in-itself (i.e. first-category) is independent of ZFC.

However, I don't have the required mathematical maturity to finish reading it. I believe the hard part is the CDH property. Any hint? (In particular, I prefer a counterexample in the plane $\Bbb R^2$)

---

Related: [A locally connected metric space of first category](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/830639/a-locally-connected-metric-space-of-first-category) (yet unanswered)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X=\mathbb{Q}\times \mathbb{R}\cup \mathbb{R}\times\{0\}\subset\mathbb{R}^2$.  Then $X$ is path-connected, but it is the union of the countably many lines $\{q\}\times\mathbb{R}$ for $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}\times\{0\}$, each of which is closed with empty interior.

Comment: OK, it seems I've asked a stupid question... Do you have any idea regarding the linked one (the locally connected one)?

Comment: @YuiToCheng: Yep, a small modification of my example works--see the answer I've added there.

Comment: @DavidMitra: Any ball in the plane intersects infinitely many of the vertical lines, so no single line contains all of the intersection with $X$.

Comment: Right. Sorry for being dense.